# Error on execute of linq query in linqpad

Tags: c#, linq

I need to get sql query of this linq query.I use linqpad .
I use a variable call with `Id` .When execute linq query get error that

> ) or end of expression expected (change the Query Language to 'C# Statements' for multi-statement queries)

Query language is C# Expression.

How to solve this?

```
Id=110000;
from u in BusProvinces
where (from s in BusProvinces
       join buscities in BusCities on s.Id equals buscities.ProvinceId
       join buspath in BusPaths on buscities.Id equals buspath.DesId
       where (buspath.DepId == Id || Id == 0)
       select s.Id).Contains(u.Id)
select u
```

[image]

Comment: The answer is in the error statement. Change the query language.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you mixed two types of `Query Languages` here.
While `Id=110000;` is  a `single-line statement`,

```
from u in BusProvinces
where (from s in BusProvinces
       join buscities in BusCities on s.Id equals buscities.ProvinceId
       join buspath in BusPaths on buscities.Id equals buspath.DesId
       where (buspath.DepId == Id || Id == 0)
       select s.Id).Contains(u.Id)
select u
```

Is an `Expression`.

Simple solution: Wrap you Linq expression in a `var`.

```
var query = (from u in BusProvinces
where (from s in BusProvinces
       join buscities in BusCities on s.Id equals buscities.ProvinceId
       join buspath in BusPaths on buscities.Id equals buspath.DesId
       where (buspath.DepId == Id || Id == 0)
       select s.Id).Contains(u.Id)
select u);
```

Full code:

```
Id=110000;
var query = (from u in BusProvinces
where (from s in BusProvinces
       join buscities in BusCities on s.Id equals buscities.ProvinceId
       join buspath in BusPaths on buscities.Id equals buspath.DesId
       where (buspath.DepId == Id || Id == 0)
       select s.Id).Contains(u.Id)
select u);
```

Comment: Error: ) or end of expression expected (change the Query Language to 'C# Statements' for multi-statement queries)

Answer (score 1):

Change the query language to `C# statements` from the tool bar above code editor:

[image]

Comment: Error: ; expected

Invalid expression term 'in'

Comment: There are several `in` keywords in your LINQ query. Can you please try to narrow down the culprit?

Comment: No .This is not possible

Comment: Are you able to go past the error `) or end of expression expected (change the Query Language to 'C# Statements' for multi-statement queries)` you have mentioned in your original question?